# Cruisecontrol.net nant results different from non-cc.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, nantcontrib

I've a nant script that builds a VS2008 solution. When I run it myself by typing 'nant' in the command line all the correct DLLs are copied to the respective bin directories. But when Cruisecontrol performs the CI build no DLLs are copied to the bin directories.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, dear Mr. Flibble, is that you have specified "test" as the target in the cc.net config which is overrigind the default target (build) that gets executed when executing nant from the commandline.

Comment: Yup, that'd be in the environment by golly.

Answer (score 0):

Very probably there is something in your environment not in the Cruise Control environment.  Add something in the CruiseControl build (like setting verbose on nant) and confirm you have the same paths set up.

Comment: Thanks Charlie.
What do you mean the CC enviornment? 
Does CC not just call the nant script and let it do its thing? What aspects of the enviornment could I be influencing when I just type 'nant' from the commandline?